# ssh tunneling a local display to another server

Tags: ssh, x11, solaris, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I have a GUI test stand simulation connected to some hardware that is under test. The test stand is a Sun Sparc Ultra 2 SunOs 5.7. The simulation software checks to see if your running your display on `:0.0`. If not it won't apply power.  We do not have the source to re-write the simulation to not check this. I have a need to "See" what is being displayed on the local terminal. I have tried `x11vnc` but it seems that Xsun might not support the record extension.  SSH -X sets the DISPLAY to `:10.0` so that is out. I really need to port forward the 6000 port to the say the 6001 port on my windows box running cgwin. (I am assuming 6001 is `:1.0` and is what my x server on my windows box will be listing too). Is any of this possible I am at whits end.

Here is the offending code.

```c
/* Console can always access the HW */
if (xserver != (char *) NULL)
{
    /* if the first two characters are ":0" */
    if ((xserver[0] == ':') && (xserver[1] == '0'))
        termtype = TERMINAL_LOCAL;
    else if (uname(&utshost) == 0)
    {
        nnlen = strlen(utshost.nodename);
        if ((int) strlen(xserver) >= (int) (nnlen + 2))
        {
            if ((strncmp(xserver, utshost.nodename, nnlen) == 0) &&
                    (xserver[nnlen] == ':') && (xserver[nnlen + 1] == '0'))
                termtype = TERMINAL_LOCAL;
            else
                termtype = TERMINAL_REMOTE;
        } /* END if */
    } /* END if/else */
} /* END if */
```

I get this when running `xdpyinfo -queryExtensions` (truncated for relevancy):

```
name of display:    localhost:0.0  
version number:    11.0  
vendor string:    The Cygwin/X Project  
vendor release number:    11001000  
maximum request size:  16777212 bytes  
motion buffer size:  256  
bitmap unit, bit order, padding:    32, LSBFirst, 32  
image byte order:    LSBFirst  
number of supported pixmap formats:    7  
supported pixmap formats:  
    depth 1, bits_per_pixel 1, scanline_pad 32  
    depth 4, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32  
    depth 8, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32  
    depth 15, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32  
    depth 16, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32  
    depth 24, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32  
    depth 32, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32  
keycode range:    minimum 8, maximum 255  
focus:  window 0x200023, revert to PointerRoot  
number of extensions:    22  
    BIG-REQUESTS  (opcode: 132)  
    Composite  (opcode: 146)  
    DAMAGE  (opcode: 147, base event: 90, base error: 149)  
    DOUBLE-BUFFER  (opcode: 138, base error: 138)  
    DPMS  (opcode: 139)  
    GLX  (opcode: 148, base event: 91, base error: 150)  
    Generic Event Extension  (opcode: 128)  
    MIT-SCREEN-SAVER  (opcode: 133, base event: 82)  
    RANDR  (opcode: 143, base event: 88, base error: 146)  
    RECORD  (opcode: 137, base error: 137)  
    RENDER  (opcode: 142, base error: 141)  
    SGI-GLX  (opcode: 148, base event: 91, base error: 150)  
    SHAPE  (opcode: 129, base event: 64)  
    SYNC  (opcode: 134, base event: 83, base error: 133)  
    X-Resource  (opcode: 145)  
    XC-MISC  (opcode: 136)  
    XFIXES  (opcode: 141, base event: 86, base error: 139)  
    XFree86-Bigfont  (opcode: 140)  
    XINERAMA  (opcode: 144)  
    XInputExtension  (opcode: 130, base event: 65, base error: 128)  
    XKEYBOARD  (opcode: 135, base event: 85, base error: 136)  
    XTEST  (opcode: 131)  
default screen number:    0
```

When I ssh name@server.com The $DISPLAY is servername:0.0 which is local but I can not see.
When I ssh -X name@server.com The $DISPLAY is localhost:0.0 which my simulation sees as remote.

Comment: x11vnc has a nxrecord command line option: see http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html#opt-noxrecord

Comment: It might help to know what extensions the Sun X server supports. Post the output of `xdpyinfo -ext all` (if that option doesn't exist, try `xdpyinfo -queryExtensions`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the simulation software really checks that the display number is 0, you can arrange for your remote display to be 0. Make sure you're not running `Xsun` locally or run it on a different display (e.g. `Xsun :1`). In the OpenSSH server configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, add the line `X11DisplayOffset 0`.

If you connect over ssh, the `DISPLAY` environment variable will be set to `localhost:0.0` (having set `X11DisplayOffset` as above). This is (for all practical purposes) synonymous to `localhost:0` which your application accepts, so you can put this in your `.profile`:

```
DISPLAY=${DISPLAY%.0}
```

If the simulation software wants a local display `:0`, you can try running it in Xvfb (**v**irtual **f**rame**b**uffer **X** server, I don't know if it's shipped with Solaris). As above, don't run an X server locally on display `:0`, run it on `:1` if at all. With Xvfb, you can't connect to the display easily, but you can see stills of the screens.

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 -fbdir /tmp &
DISPLAY=:1 simulation-program &
xwud -in /tmp/Xvfb_screen0
```

Alternatively, you might try an X server that displays in a window, such as Xnest, Xephyr or VNC — again, if you're running a local X server at all on the Sun machine, run it on display `:1`. For example, with VNC:

```
vncserver :1
```

and you can even connect to that server with a VNC viewer on your Windows machine.

Comment: it checks localhost:0.0

Comment: @Paul Ok, here are a few more things you can try. I can't test if my suggestions work since I don't have a Solaris 7 machine around, let alone your simulation software. Do you need help finding how to change the display number of the local X server?

Comment: Added offending code. See know way around this.

Comment: @Paul Can't you recompile the code without this check? Given what you've posted, any of the solutions I propose would work, if you can arrange to run `Xsun` on a display other than `:0`. All this takes is adding `:1` on the `Xsun` command line; I don't know where to control that on Solaris, but probably in a file under `/etc`.

Comment: No I can't recompile the code. The problem is that the DISPLAY var is localhost:0.0. It really does not like that. Now I have done this. I did this export DISPLAY=:0.0 then I SSH'd just using SSH me@server. I echoed $DISPLAY it was server:0.0. Which should work looking at the above c code.

Comment: Problem is I get this. Xlib: connection to "server:0.0" refused by server
Xlib: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
xhost:  unable to open display "server:0.0"

Comment: @Paul Re `.0`: Oh, I missed that. Yes, ssh sets `DISPLAY` to `localhost:$number.0`, but fortunately that's very easy to solve since the `.0` part is optional (see my edit). Re the invalid cookie: what exactly are you doing? I thought you were connecting over ssh with `X11DisplayOffset 0`, in which case you shouldn't get that message.

Comment: localhost is the problem. it needs to be the name of the box or nothing.